# How to tell to tox use trusted host and index?

Tags: python, pip, tox

I use the following usage for pip3 to install modules from my host:

```
pip3 install tox -i http://myhost/sample+ --trusted-host
```

I downloaded a bog code.It uses `tox` for installing modules.
How can I tell to `tox` use myhost for installing modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [install_command](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command) option from `tox`.

This should result in a command like this within your tox.ini configuration:

```
[testenv:your_env]
install_command=pip install --index-url=http://myhost/sample+ --trusted-host=http://myhost/sample+ {opts} {packages}
```